# Pinging/connecting to server.domain.local never works, but server does when the search domain is specified

Tags: networking

This is a bit of a weird one. I'm running ubuntu on a Windows domain. If I type "ping server" I can ping correctly and I can connect without any problems. It looks up my search domain (domain.local) and everything is hunky dory.

Problem is when I try to ping server.domain.local. It just can't look up the server and comes back with "ping: unknown host server.domain.local"

Part of me thinks that the name servers aren't set correctly, but I wonder if there is something I can do to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't a valuable name resolution (DNS) in your network add the needed addresses to */etc/hosts*.

See [man hosts](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/hosts.5.html)